# How to change text color in a PApplet GLabel

Tags: java, awt

I am very new to Java, so I wanted to make a simple example project using PApplets and NetBeans:

I want it to look like : [image: This]

But instead it looks like: [image: That]

I cant figure out how to add color to it, and when I try to use the same font(IBM Plex Sans Bold) it looks choppy and bad. For this I am using g4p_controls and java.awt.Font.and the NeatBeans IDE.

Hope you guys can help me out! Here is my code:

```
import processing.core.*; 
import g4p_controls.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import static processing.core.PApplet.println;
import static processing.core.PConstants.JAVA2D;

 public class Test extends PApplet
 {
//make sure to change the name here too
static String[] program = {"Test"};

    GLabel title;
    Font font, heaadingfont;
public void setup()
{

    size(800, 400, JAVA2D);
            //CPU

            title = new GLabel(this,183,4,507,60);
            font= new Font("IBM Plex Sans Bold",1,40);
            title.setFont(font);
            title.setText("Title");


}


public void draw()
{
    background(255, 255, 225); 

}

//this is needed to run the program
public static void main (String ags[])
{

    PApplet.main(program);
}
```

}

Let me know If I missed some information! I used the G4P.jar and the core,jar library's.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link: https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/tutorial/UsingTheGraphicsPackage.html

It says you should be able to set it as follows:

```
setBackground(bg);
```